# Can I change a Frame of a VBoxLayout in PyQt 5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm actually trying to change things in my QVBoxLayout Frame in PyQt 5 but they seem to import all settings from my previous Frame.

Here's my code:

```
class UpdateFrameVBox (QtWidgets.QFrame):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()


    self.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;'
                       'border: 5px solid #4f4f51;'
                       'border-radius: 5px;'
                       'margin: 5px;'
                       'padding: 5px;')

    self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()


    for i in range (5):
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame())
```

Is there any way for me to change only the frame of thoses VBoxLayouts?

Thank you for the pacience, and I'm sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the style sheets are cascading. That is, it inherits from its parent unless you override it in the child. That being said, it looks like you are missing an opening `{` in your style sheet. When a style sheet is bad, it silently ignores it and keeps the parent's. Try trimming down the style sheet to something minimal that will show an obvious change, and then build up from there.

Comment: that { in my code is there because i tryed to solve my problem with a resource that i found in one topic that is to put  '.UpdateFrameVBox{ in the beggining of my setStyleSheet. I already edited it, thank you :)

Comment: In that case, can you provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: For example : In my code, if I change the border to 10px  instead of 5px the outside frame will apply those changes but the others internal frames that i add in a VBoxLayout will also change. I don't want that to change, i want thoses to have they own StyleSheet.

Comment: Actually you already solved my problem metal, thank you. I called the frame as test and set test = QtWidget.QFrame() inside my for... after that i set that test with a new StyleSheet and it works just fine. Anyway, thank you for the support.